# jQuery NoUiSlider doesn't work with Mootools

Tags: jquery, slider, mootools, conflict

afer I upgrade slider to version 6 , slider disapear on mouse down
I find out the problem is Mootools but I can't find where :(
I create a smiple slider:

`<div id='test'></div>`

```
jQuery("#test").noUiSlider({
            range: {
                'min' : 0,
                'max' : 5000
            }
            ,step : 50
            ,start: [1000, 4000]
            ,behaviour: 'tap'
            ,connect: true
            ,direction: 'rtl'
        });
```

Check this plz:

http://jsfiddle.net/jixa/5cDgJ/

Comment: that was quite weird actually. Can you not use the Mootools slider instead?

Comment: No because I have wrote a couple of function  for this slider in jquery(for v5) and I prefer to use jQuery and I love this plugin very much.

Comment: this seems caused by mootools-more, for some reason. what do you use it for (-more) - this is a generic build you got with EVERYTHING. never seen a need for that, you should customize your build.

Comment: literally everything. http://mootools.net/more/065f2f092ece4e3b32bb5214464cf926 - unless you actually use it, remove mootools-more altogether. chances are your plugin does $() at some point where mootools has it and calls up methods from -more. post source of noUiSlider (github etc).

Comment: I need mootools-more becuase some extensions still need it.

Comment: I don't think '$()' make the problem because the structure of noUiSlider is:
(function(e){ // code
})(window.jQuery||window.Zepto);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because MooTools is interfering with the event management in jQuery. Both libraries attempt to handle an event called `slide`, and unfortunatly, MooTools goes first. The reason you are seeing this in noUiSlider 6 and not 5 is because it changed it's event handling from a callback to actual events.

There a two ways to fix this:

- Removed the conflicting part from MooTools-more, assuming you don't
  need this;
- Find nd replace 'slide' in the noUiSlider source. If you
  change it to `xSlide`, for example, this example should be gone.
  You'll have to do this again if you update in the future.

For what it is worth; jQueryUI seems to suffer from the same issue. Perhaps this bug tracker page can be of some assistance:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4168